# Azure DocumentDB (CosmosDB?) Timstamp Issue

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-functions

I have an Azure DocumentDB collection that I'm writing time-stamped documents to via an Event Hub triggered function.  The timestamp that *I'm* writing to the document (my_timestamp) originates from the function that processes the event, and I've confirmed that it is accurate.

The problem that I'm encountering is that the `_ts` metadata timestamp that's created by DocumentDB itself is showing a unix timestamp value that's a number of seconds previous to the timestamp I'm creating, i.e., it's actually applying a timestamp that's earlier than the beginning of the function execution that creates the document...

It appears that this may be a quirk in the underlying DocumentDB mechanics.

Anyway, I wanted to see if anyone else is encountering this discrepancy.  Here are the timestamps as they appear in my document:

```
"my_timestamp": 1499301915, // here's my timestamp that originates from the Azure Function
"_ts":          1499301899  // and here's the timestamp created by DocDB?
```

And the code used to derive `my_timestamp` in the Azure Function:

```
var timeStamp = + Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
```

Comment: Can you also share the function code so we can see how `my_timestamp` is calculated?

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, The `_ts` field is a unix-style epoch timestamp representing the date and time and it would be updated every time when a document is modified.

> Anyway, I wanted to see if anyone else is encountering this discrepancy.

According to your description, I checked this issue and I encountered the same issue for some times. But when I check this issue today, I could not reproduce this issue, Here is my code for testing:

**Javascript**

```
var doc={
    timestamp:Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000)
    };

context.bindings.outputDocument = doc;

setTimeout( function() { 
    context.res={
        status:200,
        body:JSON.stringify(doc)
    };
    context.done();
}, 10*1000);
```

Query result via Query Explorer from azure portal:

[image]

Also, I have checked with azure function C# template and DocumentDB client SDK for adding new document. If this issue persists on your side, I assumed that you could add your feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/355860-azure-functions).

Comment: Thanks for the information @Bruce Chen, that confirms my understanding of the _ts field. I'm still experiencing the issue, and your comment "I checked this issue and I encountered the same issue for some times" is concerning to me; do you have a sense of why this issue occurs?  I'll submit feedback as you suggest, but this seems like a potentially serious bug in DocDB/CosmosDB...